# How can I call a .bat file instead of writing the whole path to the .exe?

Tags: php, batch-file, command-line

I have **two** PHP versions that I want to execute depending on the situation. I have setup `PATH` so that when I type `php` there is executed the right version of PHP in the folder `C:\xampp\php`.

However, I also have an older version of PHP in the folder `C:\old-xampp\php`. Of course, I can't add also that folder path to `PATH` as there would be two folders with a file with the name `php.exe` and used would be always `php.exe` in first folder in `PATH`.

At the moment I have to type `C:\old-xampp\php\php my-command-here` every time I want to execute my old PHP.

Is there a way to create a .bat file in a `PATH` folder with the name `old-php.bat` that would act as if I typed `C:\old-xampp\php\php`?

I am open to another method to do it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be written into a batch file `old-php.bat` stored in a folder of which path is listed in string value of environment variable `Path` the command line:

```
@C:\old-xampp\php\php.exe %*
```

`%*` references all arguments passed to the batch file exactly as passed to the batch file. This is explained by the usage help of command **CALL** output on running `call /?` in a command prompt window. Argument 0 is the string used to start the batch file which is not included by `%*`.

It would be also possible to create in a folder of which path is listed in string value of environment variable `Path` a hard link or a symbolic link with a name like `old-php.exe` which links to `C:\old-xampp\php\php.exe` by using once [MKLINK](https://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html).